# Why people do not answer my questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have posted three questions within a week, but I still have not received any response for those questions. Why?

Even silly questions like `How to extract Uranium from the sun using C++?` usually get answered by people.

Comment: Probably the questions were poorly phrased or maybe you have not put enough and proper tags.

Comment: Have you read this:  http://www.tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: If your questions aren't getting answered, perhaps you need to be clearer/more specific in what you are asking, or provide more detail and code examples to help people understand your problem.

Comment: Everything is well written and clear!

Comment: Flagged as not a real question.  If nobody answers your questions it is because you are either not giving good information, or running into unusual or rare problems.  Try contributing to the site to earn some points and you can post a bounty on your questions.  Bounties will help motivate people to answer.

Comment: @DingDongDev - You haven't put `PHP` tag for example. If you put it more people will see it. You have put only `soap` tag which only a few people are watching.

Comment: Always remember that the *quality* of your questions is **directly proportional** to the quality of the answers you can expect to receive. The more time you spend writing questions, the more time people are willing to spend writing answers. And thus, the more helpful those answers will be.

Comment: @forsvarir: Please *do not* use URL shorteners on this site.

Comment: @AlEvertt, ummm why?

Comment: @Al Everett: In my defense, I posted it on the main SO site, not on *this* site.  On SO, the link is used fairly commonly.  Is there a rule saying we're not allowed to use them that I am not aware of?

Comment: Yeah, I'm about the most vocal opponent of obfuscated URLs that's out there. But the one @forsvarir posted is *extremely* common on Stack Overflow, and I think is acceptable because it's immediately recognizable.

Comment: @AlEverett: that's a common one @JohnP that is automatically blocked by Forefront.

Comment: @will apologies if this is obvious, but what's Forefront?

Comment: @JohnP: One of many proxies which control traffic in and out of business networks.

Answer (score 18):

I had a look at your questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070198/

[How I pass multiple parameters to a soap method using nusoap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067233/)

[SOAP returning "Internal Server Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057370/)

You haven't added the all important PHP tag. This means it won't show up for people who are following the PHP tag and you're going to get less eyes on it.

[One of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067233/) don't give enough detail. People here will help if they can, nobody is going to ignore your question just to spite you. But how can we help you if you don't give us enough details. Having a good problem definition helps a lot.

You should also read this FAQ entry on steps you can take (although I hardly think 'yesterday' is old)

[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: Also all three questions are hard on the edge of being closed as `not a real question`, in my opinion, especially "multiple parameters" one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be patient. Answering questions accurately requires some level of expertise at least, so you need to wait till questions grab the attentions of the experts. Also perhaps make sure that the questions you ask are clearly worded, and are not ambiguous (vague). Use the right tags. All this will improve chances of getting answered faster.